# Mathematica image won't display

Tags: plotting, graphics, complex, regions

I need some help getting RegionPlot to display.
Running this code:

```
region[z_] := Re[z] >= 1;
f[z_] := 1/z;
g = InverseFunction[f];

h[z_] = 1+1/z;
hin = InverseFunction[h];
hp = RegionPlot[region[hin[g[x + I y]]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}]

h2[z_] = 2+1/z;
h2in = InverseFunction[h2];
h2p = RegionPlot[region[h2in[g[x + I y]]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}]

h3[z_] = 3+1/z;
h3in = InverseFunction[h3];
h3p = RegionPlot[region[h3in[g[x + I y]]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}]
```

displays three disks decreasing in size, in the complex plane.
However, when I try to run the fourth:

```
h4[z_] = 4+1/z;
h4in = InverseFunction[h4];
h4p = RegionPlot[region[h4in[g[x + I y]]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}]
```

The resulting plot is empty. I think because the circle is so small, Mathematica ignores it. Is there a way to increase the resolution or something like that, to get Mathematica to display small images?

Answer (score 1):

You could set more initial points:

```
RegionPlot[region[h4in[g[x + I y]]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}, 
 PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thank you!